# How to Generate Background Color of Baked Texture from Island Margins?

Tags: python, texture-baking, baking

I have a high poly model and I want to bake its diffuse texture to a low poly model.

So here is what I have:

[image]

Download the Blender file here:

[image]

The result of baking from selected to active looks like this:

[image]

However my goal is to replace the transparent background with meaningful color data. Specifically I want the color of the margins to expand into the transparent areas.
Let me show you...

the desired result should look something like this:

[image]

I don't want to do it manually.
The goal is to do it automatically with the help of the Blender Python API.

Currently I use something similar to the following code to bake with the Python API:

```py
bake_image = bpy.data.images.new('bake_image',width=2048, height=2048)
bake_node.image = bake_image
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE')
self.bake_image.filepath_raw = 'bake_image.tif'
self.bake_image.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a bigger margin without perturbing the bake itself:

[image]

So the result is:

[image]

And the models are still quite nice:

[image]

So for the api, use the margin parameter:

```
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE', margin=512)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I thought turning up the margin will result in an overlap. But I guess blurring the margin isn't an easy task? (such that it doesn't look like a barcode)

Comment: Well maybe bluring mixing 0 margin and big margin, so two bakes (or use the UV map export)... the alpha of the first could be a mask  for bluring the second... and something around mixing that with compositor and extract the view result after that... a bit long for me to do it. But you can? Yes?

Comment: Additionnaly yes previous versions of Blender did not like big margin (if I remember well).

Comment: Ok great! I'll figure out the rest on my own. Thanks for your help!